# How do I remove the leaves of a binary tree?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, recursion, binary-tree

I'm trying to remove all of the leaves. I know that leaves have no children, this is what I have so far.

```
 public void removeLeaves(BinaryTree n){  

    if (n.left == null && n.right == null){

        n = null;

    }

    if (n.left != null)

        removeLeaves(n.left);

    if (n.right != null)

        removeLeaves(n.right);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's much easier if you break this down like this:

```
public void removeLeaves(BinaryTree n){
  if (n.left != null) {
    if (n.left.isLeaf()) {
      n.removeLeftChild();
    } else {
      removeLeaves(n.left);
    }
  }
  // repeat for right child
  // ...
}
```

`isLeaf`, `removeLeftChild` and `removeRightChild` should be trivial to implement.

Answer (score 7):

`n = null;` won't help you, since `n` is just a local variable of your function. Instead, you'd need to set `n.left = null;` or `n.right = null;` on the parent.

I won't give you a complete solution, since this smells a lot like homework, but you could, for example, add a return value to your function to indicate whether the node in question is a leaf or not and take appropriate actions in the parent (after the call to `removeLeaves`).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of n = null, it should be:

```
if(n.parent != null)
  {
    if(n.parent.left == n)
    {
      n.parent.left = null;
    } 
    else if(n.parent.right == n)
    {
      n.parent.right == null);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This will fail with a `NullPointerException` if the root is a leaf itself.

Comment: What I'm doing is a data structure, meaning that I built the BinaryTree class and in this case the parent would be n.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java passes references by values `n = null;` simply does not work. With this line n was pointing to the leaf and now points to nothing. So you aren't actually removing it from the parent, you are just rerouting a dummy local reference. For the solution do what Matthew suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple **java** method to **delete leaf nodes** from binary tree

```
public BinaryTreeNode removeLeafNode(BinaryTreeNode root) {
    if (root == null)
        return null;
    else {
        if (root.getLeft() == null && root.getRight() == null) {     //if both left and right child are null
            root = null;                                             //delete it (by assigning null)
        } else {
            root.setLeft(removeLeafNode(root.getLeft()));            //set new left node 
            root.setRight(removeLeafNode(root.getRight()));          //set new right node   
        }
        return root;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy method with recusrion .

```
 public static Node removeLeaves(Node root){
          if (root == null) { 
            return null; 
        } 
        if (root.left == null && root.right == null) { 
            return null; 
        } 

        root.left = removeLeaves(root.left); 
        root.right = removeLeaves(root.right); 

        return root;
  }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to how this works. I don't see how it removes the leaves of the tree provided.

Comment: Basically we're doing this recursively, so we are calling on left and right node from root node having faith that child will remove its leaf node. Now recall the property of leaf node that is it has null in both right and left node. we're checking that, if it is so, then we're returning null from that node means that node is now returned as null.

Comment: My mistake. I see it now  `root.left = removeLeaves(root.left)` is an assignment :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 /* @author abhineet*/

public class DeleteLeafNodes {


    static class Node{
        int data;
        Node leftNode;
        Node rightNode;
        Node(int value){
            this.data = value;
            this.leftNode = null;
            this.rightNode = null;
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node root = new Node(1);
        Node lNode = new Node(2);
        lNode.leftNode = new Node(4);
        root.leftNode = lNode;
        Node rNode = new Node(3);
        rNode.rightNode = new Node(5);
        root.rightNode = rNode;
        printTree(root);
        deleteAllLeafNodes(root, null,0);
        System.out.println("After deleting leaf nodes::");
        printTree(root);

    }

    public static void deleteAllLeafNodes(Node root, Node parent, int direction){
        if(root != null && root.leftNode == null && root.rightNode == null){
            if(direction == 0){
                parent.leftNode = null;
            }else{
                parent.rightNode = null;
            }

        }
        if(root != null && (root.leftNode != null || root.rightNode != null)){
            deleteAllLeafNodes(root.leftNode, root, 0);
            deleteAllLeafNodes(root.rightNode, root, 1);
        }

    }
    public static void printTree(Node root){
        if(root != null){
            System.out.println(root.data);
            printTree(root.leftNode);
            printTree(root.rightNode);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work-

```
public boolean removeLeaves(Node n){  
    boolean isLeaf = false;
    if (n.left == null && n.right == null){
        return true;
        //n = null;
    }

    if (n!=null && n.left != null){

       isLeaf = removeLeaves(n.left);
       if(isLeaf) n.left=null; //remove left leaf
    }

    if (n!=null && n.right != null){

        isLeaf = removeLeaves(n.right);
        if(b) n.right=null; //remove right leaf
    }
    return false;

}
```